# Find dictionary in NSMutableDictionary and remove it

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsdictionary

```
    <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Rows</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>FavTitle</key>
            <string>AppliedVersion</string>
            <key>SaveName</key>
            <string>122.pdf</string>
            <key>duh</key>
            <string>Favourited</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>FavTitle</key>
            <string>Test Eng. Version</string>
            <key>SaveName</key>
            <string>dsds.pdf</string>
            <key>duh</key>
            <string>Favourited</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Trying and failing to remove things with this:

```
NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favourites.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:writablePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *newFav = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: selectedFavTitle, @"FavTitle", @"Favourited", @"duh", selectedSaveName, @"SaveName", nil];
    [[rootDict objectForKey:@"Rows"] removeObjectIdenticalTo:newFav];  
    [rootDict writeToFile:writablePath atomically: YES];
```

Its been doing my head in!
The flaw is with:

```
[[rootDict objectForKey:@"Rows"] removeObjectIdenticalTo:newFav];
```

as that does not remove the matched object

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *newFav = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: selectedFavTitle, @"FavTitle", @"Favourited", @"duh", selectedSaveName, @"SaveName", nil];
```

This line creates a new instance of `NSMutableDictionary`.  So when you call `removeObjectIdenticalTo:`, it doesn't match anything because that new instance isn't the same object as the one in `rootDict`.

You can either filter out the objects you don't want with `filterUsingPredicate:` or you can loop over `rootDict` manually to find and remove the object manually.

Comment: I'm still new to Obj-C, how would I do `filterUsingPredicate`, would it be like: `NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:selectedFavTitle, @"FavTitle", @"Favourited", @"duh", selectedSaveName, @"SaveName"];
  [rootDict filterUsingPredicate:pred];`

Comment: In general, the answer to questions of the form *"Would this work?"* is *"Why haven't you tried it for yourself?"*  Apple provide a [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be encoding problems. You didn't tell us which encoding you specified when you saved this plist file and you didn't specify one explicitly like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: for the sake of just streamlining everything I excluded that, top is plist is: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 etc....`